# Problem with WebSockets Draft

Tags: c#, jquery, websocket

I'm having some trobule with Web Sockets and Microsoft's Draft implementation. I'm using the API provided by them for the server back and as well as the Silverlight fix for browsers that don't natively support Web Sockets. The information i'm working off of comes from http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM10 and http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info
My code compiles okay, it starts to open the connection, then fails. Here's my backend server code (in a C# Console App)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets;
namespace ChatBackend
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebSocketsHost<MessageHandler>();
            host.AddWebSocketsEndpoint("ws://localhost:4502/MessageHandler");
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the MessageHandler class:

```
 class MessageHandler : WebSocketsService
{
    public override void OnMessage(string value)
    {
        string returnMessage = "You just said '" + value + "'";
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        SendMessage(returnMessage);
    }
}
```

This backend part seems to work fine. Here's the client end:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(connect, 2050);
        });

        function connect() {
            websocket = new WebSocketDraft("ws://localhost:4502/MessageHandler");
            websocket.onopen = function() {
                websocket.send("test");
            };
            websocket.onclose = function () {
                alert("DIED");
            };
            websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
                sendMessage(new message(0, event.data, 0));
            };
        }
```

EDIT: I checked my firewall and allowed the port i was using. Now the connection just hangs - it doesn't close, it doesn't open. Any ideas?

EDIT 2: I did some more research, turns out i need to remove the clientaccesspolicy.xml. Also turns out i never had it, but i WAS returning a custom 302 redirect instead of a 404 not found. Fixed that, but no progress. It just hangs.

EDIT 3: Tried turning off Anti-Virus and Firewall, no change
Thanks - let me know if i need anymore code or information up here.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus or custom proxy, just out of interest ? Also, if you have it, what happens if you add a reference to that web-service via Visual Studio ? as that tries to process it, you may get a better error ...

Comment: @Russ C No custom proxy besides fiddler - and it still doesn't work when i turn fiddler off. anti-virus - MS Security Essentials, which shouldn't be tampering with my ports or anything.

Comment: Shouldn't be no, but I wonder if it knows about the WS:// protocol ?

Comment: @Russ tried turning it off - no change. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working! Turns out i had to add clientaccesspolicy.xml to the root folder of the default website on my server. I thought i had to delete it - i misread some information and promptly forgot about it. Moral of the story: read the readme!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Firebug or something and put a breakpoint on this line in jquery.slws.js (assuming its the one you're using!)

```
this.slws = slCtl.Content.services.createObject("websocket");
```

And then step through and see where it fails ?

Comment: according to the video (link in original question) instantiating the websocket object DOES open it. i'm scanning the video for any errors i may have made.

Comment: When the socket opens he sends a message. I'd presume creating a new websocket opens the connection.

Comment: It's just in the code snippet I've seen from his links, .send is called outside of the onxxx.

Comment: .send is used to actually send some data down the stream  - it's not the same as opening it. I'm trying to call that once the connection opens - which it never seems to do.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that - just looked at the plugin and updated my answer.

Comment: I stepped through - no error! the socket is created successfully!

Comment: yes, very. i'm gonna walk through one more time and look veeerry carefully at stuff.

Comment: @Russ C thanks for all your help! you set me on the path to finding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL definitely looks like it matches the setting on your server side. It's really hard to find any examples of WebSockets actually being used since it's still such a new technology, but from what I could follow of the only working example I could find (it was on the html5labs site), I think maybe you're trying to write to the socket before it's finished opening. In the example I found, it looked like they check the readyState property of the socket, and only try to `send` if readyState === 1. The socket in that example gets opened by tying into the `$(document).ready` event, and send gets called from a button click.

Comment: Thanks Joel - but it's not seeming to work - onclose gets called before onopen, and my attempt to send data is inside onopen. Plus, the video (in the question above) that i was following didn't use this readyState property either... that's what's really odd. i followed the video to perfection.